# Removing AnchorPane from one GridPane and adding it to another causes it to be offset

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-8

I am writing a Scrabble GUI in JavaFX. My 'board' and my 'tile rack' are both GridPanes. Each index of the board contains an extension of an AnchorPane (called SquareWithBorder), and 'tiles' (called LetterTileWithValue) are added to this when the user places the tile on the board. The result is a GridPane, containing AnchorPanes, some of which contain Tiles (my tiles are also AnchorPane extensions). For context, my model for a tile is the Tile class.

My problem is that when I move a tile AnchorPane from the rack GridPane to the board GridPane the tile appears offset to the right. How far the tile is offset depends on where it was positioned in the rack. The tile in the 1st position of the rack will appear on the board in the square that I clicked. The tile in the 2nd position of the rack will be slightly offset, the tile in the 3rd position will be slightly *more* offset, etc.. If I place all of the tiles into the 1st index of the Rack GridPane then all of the tiles will have the same offset when I move them into the Board. The offset is directly related to the tile's position in the rack.

Below is a screenshot which hopefully demonstrates this.

[image: The red lines show where the first two tiles were placed on the board. The 1st tile ('f') was placed in the top left, and each subsequent tile was placed below the others.]

The moving of tiles from the rack to the board is implemented with onMouseClicked event handlers and listeners attached to the ObservableLists which model the board and the rack. Below are some code snippets.

```
public void addTileToRack(Tile t) {
    LetterTileWithValue tempTile = new LetterTileWithValue(t.getToken(), t.getValue());
    tempTile.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            mainApp.setSelectedTile(tempTile);
            tempTile.setSelected();
        }

    });
    rack.addRow(0, tempTile);
}
```

This method is called when a tile object is added to the model in the mainApp class. It is in the controller class for the view in the screenshot.

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    for(int i = 0; i < (15*15); i++) {
        SquareWithBorder tempSquare = new SquareWithBorder(i);
        tempSquare.setMainApp(this.mainApp);
        tempSquare.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                LetterTileWithValue selectedTile = mainApp
                        .getSelectedTile();
                if (selectedTile != null) {
                    selectedTile.setRow(tempSquare.getIndex() / 15);
                    selectedTile.setCol(tempSquare.getIndex() % 15);
                    tempSquare.setTile(selectedTile);
                    move.put(selectedTile.getLetter(),
                            tempSquare.getIndex());
                    mainApp.clearSelectedTile();
                }
            }

        });
        board.add(tempSquare, i % 15, i / 15);
    }
}
```

This method is also in the controller class for the game's view.

```
public void setTile(LetterTileWithValue tile) {
    if (tile != null) {
        ObservableList<Node> children = this.getChildren();
        tile.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(!tile.isFinalMove()) {
                    System.out.printf("[DEBUG - SWB setTile] Letter: %s\n",  
                            tile.getLetter());
                    mainApp.addToRack(new Tile(tile.getLetter()));
                    children.remove(tile);
                }
            }

        });
        children.add(tile);
    }
}
```

This method is in the SquareWithBorder class, and is called when a Square is clicked while one of the rack tiles is selected.